# Can we update properties of a css selector at runtime through XML?

Tags: css, xml

I have a CSS file & view (XML) file in our code. 
There is a selector, which is having attributes (x, y position, image to display, etc...) for displaying a picture.
We need to display update the attributes of the selector at runtime (specifically image to display), because we will get the image from other source at runtime.

So, is there any way to update attributes of a selector at runtime?

Comment: Yaa, you can update that particular css at runtime

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. But I am not expert on CSS & XML.   Please suggest some way to update the attributes (image in the below example) at runtime.                                                                            For Example:                                                                                                     #icon {
  x:15; y:9;
  image: "include://Icon_mail.png";
}